# Crest ErrorHandler get response data

Tags: java, android, rest

we are developing an android app and we want to make use of the crest lib. the web service we are using returns in some situations 400 for bad request with additional response data in json format. we have a response handler for success and an error handler for the bad requests. is it possible to get the returned data in the error handler?

error handler

```
public class RestErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{

@Override
public <T> T handle(Request request, Exception e) throws Exception {

    // here we need to check the code returned from the 
    // web service in case of a bad request
    return null;
}

}
```

bad request looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 59
Date: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 15:01:23 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: session=A…...
Status: 400
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
{"status":false,"code":"403","message":"wrong credentials"}
```

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to dig up such old question, but I have also stumbled upon this issue and others might find the answer helpful.

If the exception is http-related, then it can be cast to `org.codegist.crest.io.RequestException` which has `getResponse()` method.

More info here: https://github.com/codegist/crest/issues/9